# Continuous-time loop computer for NP problems?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, electronics

In [NP problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) we can cheaply (polynomial time) test if a given input is satisfying, but the difficulty is that there is an exponential number of possible inputs - the question is if e.g. there is a satisfying input.

Imagine there is a simple hardware implementation of verifier (e.g. in form of [3-SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)): as a few layers of logic gates, returns 1 if the input is satisfying, 0 otherwise.

Now build a circuit which returns "input+1" (cyclically) for non-satifying inputs, and "input" for a satisfying one ... and connect its output to input:

[image]

So the original NP problem has became finding a fixed-point of such loop. If this electronic circuit has a clock (is synchronized), it would test one input per step, until reaching a fixed point - a solution.

**But what if there is no clock/synchronization?** Just hydrodynamics of electrons flowing around the circuit, trying to stabilize the flow to minimize fluctuations. Like NOT gate connected into a loop should create [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator) (I think it strongly depends on technology of gates?).

**Could such unsynchronized continuous circuit be faster - use some shortcuts while finding fixed point of the loop: solution of our problem?**

While we know that with clock it stabilizes in exponential time, without the clock there are basically 3 options:

1. Without clock it will no longer stabilize,
2. It will stabilize in comparable time,
3. It will stabilize essentially faster (using some shortcuts in the search).

Which is the proper possibility? Can we say anything certain without experiment (ASIC?) - are there some arguments pro or against any of these possibilities?

Comment: No, in the system as you describe it, you still have to resolve the non-trivial behaviour in time, and the totality of that behaviour is exponential in the input to the circuit. Just omitting the clock doesn't help with that.

Comment: You're right. If you can find fixed points quickly, than you can indeed solve NP-complete problems. But nobody knows how to do that with "hydrodynamics of electrons" (or any other mainstream physics, for that matter). Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: Removing synchronization would make such circuit to work between discrete values, it would become a continuous search - it might lead to a total noise (depending on gate technology), but maybe physics could try to stabilize such electron flow. I think it would fluctuate between various local minima of such electron hydrodynamics, and there is probably an exponential number of them (?)

Comment: Ok, I got this spatial-loop concept after considering time-loop computers (e.g using [CPT-analogue of free electron laser](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308106/causality-in-cpt-symmetry-ananlogue-of-free-electron-laser-stimulated-absorbtio), especially that [Shor's algorithm also uses retrocausality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351534/shors-algorithm-its-causality-and-similar-exploitation-of-qm) ). Here is a [2008 discussion](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/continious-time-loop-computer.86973/).

Comment: Could anybody explained why it is "on hold"? This is just a question about behavior of electronic circuit - a few layers of logic gates, connected in a loop, without clock to synchronize its behavior - why it was classified as "off -topic" or not belonging to mainstream physics? I can modify it, but first I need to understand what is the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that specified enough to say how the "logic gates" will behave?

Comment: Logic gates are usually built with transistors, basing on some nonlinearity and requiring delivering energy to e.g. to support circular flow here, like oscillator from NOT gates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator . There are various ways for choosing those nonlinearities - the details is a difficult question for electronics expert (maybe worth to explore), but my question here is if in principle this way of asking physics to solve our problem might be faster than with clock? If some "avoiding turbulences of electron flow" could help finding a shortcut in this nearly analog circuit?

Comment: So you're asking: can I remove the clock from a circuit and run it, and then maybe some magic happens, and I can solve NP-complete problems faster than conventional circuits? This question probably should have been closed as too vague – you're not really being very clear about the "magic" part – and not as non-mainstream physics (unless you take the "magic" literally).

Comment: We have a circuit for which we know that with clock it stabilizes in a fixed point in EXPONENTIAL time. Now we remove the clock and there are basically 3 possibilities: 1) it will not stabilize 2) it will stabilize in comparable time as with clock 3) it will stabilize essentially faster (find shortcuts). This is a legit physical question, for which I don't know the answer, cannot even just exclude any of these possibilities (?), probably for certainty it would require experiment. I would really appreciate any argument pro or against any of these possibilities.

Comment: @PeterShor , as this question is far nontrivial, personally I have no idea what is the proper answer, instead of claiming anything I'm rather pessimistic (also regarding related adiabatic QC), I don't believe a simple argument could provide a definite answer here (probably experiment would be needed), here is starting a discussion: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/continuous-time-loop-computer-for-np-problems.930110/

Comment: People have been occasionally trying to use vaguely similar ideas to yours to solve NP-complete problems for the last 40 years. None of them have worked, and most computer scientists have become convinced that they're a complete waste of effort. Unless you have some compelling reason that this one isn't going to suffer the same fate as all these others, I believe that closing this question was the right thing to do.

Comment: Great, maybe you could suggest some interesting literature on non-standard physical approaches to NP? What should I look for? Converting NP-complete problem into a physical system is not an easy task, the above "loop computer" is kind of direct way so might be considered earlier, but I couldn't find any information in literature when I was looking in 2008 (?)

Comment: Scott Aaronson [NP-Complete Problems and Physical Reality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0502072.pdf). Vergis, Steiglitz, Dickinson, [The Complexity of Analog Computation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.87.1773). And you should be able to find more by looking at their bibliographies and the papers that cite them.

Comment: @PeterShor, thank you, I have read them but the only similar I see there is time-loop computer: instead of wire to close the loop, using some retrocausality (like CPT analogue of laser in linked thread, since proposing it in 2009 I also wasn't able to get explanation why it shouldn't work?). It seems my question remains unanswered (?), might require experiment - personally I think 2) is the least likely: if such loop would have tendency to stabilize, it doesn't have to go through exponentially long evolution ... but I have a feeling that it won't stabilize, maybe some "shaking" could help (?)

Comment: There's a fourth possibility: it stabilizes at some state that gives no information about the desired solution.

Comment: Indeed, there is probably exponential number of local minima, where some gates are between two binary cases (details depend on the actual nonlinearity in transistors). We can "shake it" if from local minimum by adding noise - the procedure should e.g.: shake, wait, test, repeat. It still might require expected exponential number of such cycles - the question is how attracting stable flow is?

Comment: I came up with https://oeis.org/A186202 trying to solve GI as a permutation checking problem, and https://github.com/chadbrewbaker/endoscope was extending it to transformation semigroups. I'd fuzz the Z3 SMT solver to get small circuits that take a long time to SAT/UNSAT.  Last comment sounds like timescale parallel Molecular Dynamics, https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4818328  - full boundary condition would be a SAT - mini boundary on the last fan-in state?  - hack LAMMPS with "electrons" as particles -  or use https://xyce.sandia.gov/ ?

Comment: My mind's eye sees something like https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/znah/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb as useful for generating satisfying inputs to some circuits. Start with circuits that are 50% SAT inputs then crank it down to see where it breaks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/introduction-to-neural-networks/playground-exercises this shows recognition of an XOR gate, which you can make from 4 NAND gates. NAND gates are universal so you can generate large NAND circuits to test with.